# bootstrap node vs cmd/bootnode

Tags: go-ethereum, poa, clique, bootnodes, bootstrap

I am using `bootnode` as a starting/meeting point for my private POA/clique network. When I start it since one of the latest versions it says:

```
fmt.Println("Note: you're using cmd/bootnode, a developer tool.")
fmt.Println("We recommend using a regular node as bootstrap node for production deployments.")
```

How can I prevent using a bootnode process and use a "boostrap node". I cannot find any details about that in the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section **Setting Up Networking** [here](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/private-network) describes how to run a bootstrap node.

It looks like you just need to provide the flag `--nat` with the IP address of the computer/server running the code when you run the `geth` command. You need to make sure you have the port you are using open appropriately as well.

You can then use the geth console `geth attach data/geth.ipc --exec admin.nodeInfo.enr` to get the string other nodes should use to connect to your bootstrap node.