# Ethereum cluster in kubernetes

Tags: private-blockchain, bootnodes

I am trying to set up a **private** ethereum cluster in **kubernetes**. I have tried to use the [stable deprecated helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/ethereum), but it only works with older versions of the ethereum/client-go image. When I use version **1.9** or higher, I see in the bootnode logs the message `Note: you're using cmd/bootnode, a developer tool.` and the miners cannot connect to the bootnode.

Has anyone managed to make it work?

Also, reading this answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79266/bootstrap-node-vs-cmd-bootnode) in a related issue of stack exchange, I have tried to setup the cluster without a helm chart, following the guide described in the official docs of [geth ethereum](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/private-network). In this case, I see that the bootnode, tries to connect to other network ids
`DEBUG[08-04|16:04:45.776] Ethereum handshake failed id=64454cd244abc39a conn=dyndial err="network ID mismatch: 100 (!= 818945082333)"`.

I have searched all over the internet but cannot find an updated guide. Any help is deeply appreciated.